# How to detect png, jpg images using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, github, danger

Just trying to detect png and jpg images in the github pull request using DangerFile.
Here is everything that I found

```
modified_files_has_wrong_pic_formant = git.modified_files.any? { |file| /.*\.(png|jpg)/.match(File.extname(file)) }
added_files_has_wrong_pic_formant = git.added_files.any? { |file| /.*\.(png|jpg)/.match(File.extname(file)) }
```

Does it work or can you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
failure "Don't commit PNG/JPG" if (git.added_files + git.modified_files).any?(/\.(png|jpg)\z/)
```

Check all files in PR that they are not end with `.png` or `.jpg`